# httphandler path doesn't match any path after *

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I wrote an handler that should work for all the following urls:

- .../assert/a.png
- .../assert/a/b.png
- .../assert/a/b/c.png

but works only with the first one, here it is my code in the web.config file:

```
<customHandlers>
    <handler trigger="~/assert/" handler="CasImagesHandler.ashx"/>
</customHandlers>

<handlers>
    <add verb="*" path="*/assert/*.png" type="xxx.CasImagesHandler, xxx" name="CasImagesHandler"/>
</handlers>

<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="*/assert/*.png" type="xxx.CasImagesHandler, xxx" name="CasImagesHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Thanks for help